# How to find a string in between two other strings on multiple lines in php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, regex

So, I have the source code to an old website of mine with a lot of javascript arrays that are important to retrieve, but there is too much data to do it manually. I now need this data in a database, so I figured I could make some kind of parser to collect the data in a PHP array ready to insert.

The javascript array source that it will be reading from looks something like this:

```
array['john'][0] = new Array(
    'Select',
    '10',
    '20',
    '30',
);

array['john'][1] = new Array(
    'Select',
    '40',
    '83',
    '23',
);

array['jack'][0] = new Array(
    'Select',
    '47',
    '29',
    '11',
);

array['jack'][2] = new Array(
    'Select',
    '13',
    '24',
    '32',
);
```

I figured the best way was with regex, I tried to use something like `/array[[\w\W]*][[\d\D]*] = new Array(\()(.*\n?)(\)\;)/` and it picked up some of it, but it did not work well enough.

Is there a way to retrieve each individual array? That way I could take the key names and also take the values? It's been driving me crazy trying to get this to work!

Comment: This question is definitely a duplicate, where did you research?

Comment: I've been looking over Google and Stack Overflow for ages. I've found a few solutions, but none of them are working.

Comment: javascript arrays are JSON, no need to parse it yourself.

Comment: why not simply send via ajax to the server?

Comment: There's around 100 pages with similar javascript arrays (but all different depending on the page). Which is why I can't just convert it to a JSON (i won't actually be running these pages, just looking through the source codes)

I wasn't the one that coded the site at the time. Each page is individual (no shared javascript file, so I cannot simply send it via AJAX or other similar methods)

Comment: for php there is a v8 engine. http://pecl.php.net/package/v8js http://php.net/v8js/

Comment: here is an example http://php.net/manual/de/v8js.examples.php

Comment: VolkerSchukai - that looks pretty interesting. I'll check that out, thank you.

@chris85 - I never use regex so I was using the aid of a regex builder but thank you for pointing that out! It's useful to know :)

Comment: @chris85 This was EXACTLY what I needed, thank you! Do you want to write your comment up as an answer and I'll mark it as such? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is close but is missing escaping and creating incorrect character classes. This regex should find each array block for you:

```
array\['[a-zA-Z]+?'\]\[\d+\] = new Array\([\s\S]+?\);
```

`\[` is an escaped bracket, without the back slash that creates a character class which makes everything inside literal. `[a-zA-Z]+` is any alpha character (the `\w` you were using allows numbers and underscores as well, and with the `\W` it allows everything because that is the inverse), the `+` requires one or more be present. That goes until the first `]` (again escaped). We then look for the number index (\d) is a number, or it could be `[0-9]`. The `[\s\S]+?` is searching for either a whitespace or non-whitespace aka anything until it encounters `\);`. That could be exchanged for `.+?` if the `s` modifier is used.

```
/array\['[a-zA-Z]+?'\]\[\d+\] = new Array\(.+?\);/s
```

Here's a demo: https://regex101.com/r/y7zdGp/1/

I also would recommend using the data at its data object rather than its outputted format.

Comment: Really solid explanation and was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for your help.